# How to access a file in the .war classpath during unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, web-applications, freemarker

I have a web application project, and I'm trying to unit test a method that creates a file using a FreeMarker template. My method createFile() should take a MyFile type - that contains the File name to create and the rootMap FreeMarker needs and the template name - and create a file using the template I provide.

I am following the [Freemarker manual](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html/) to set a Template Loader. The problem is, I'm using the TemplateLoader setClassForTemplateLoading(Class, String) method to find the template path. This template loader uses the Class.getResource() to get the classpath.

But, since I'm using Maven, I have my java code in /src/main/java, my template in /src/main/webapp/templates/ and my test code in /src/test/java. Therefore, my Class.getResource("/") (root classpath) always returns `<PATH_TO_PROJECT>/target/test-classes/`.

Since I will be deploying a war, I cannot use the setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(File). Also, since I'm testing my app I don't have a ServletContext to use with setServletContextForTemplateLoading(Object, String).

How can I access my template folder from the test case?

Here's a simplified example of my test code (I use mockito to mock the behaviour of the MyFile class):

```
private MyFile myFile;
private FileGenerator fileGenerator;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    myFile = new MyFile(...);
    fileGenerator = new FileGenerator(myFile, ...);
}

@Test
public void shouldCreateFile() {
    final MyFile mockedMyFile = spy(file);
    final Map<String, Object> rootMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    // populates rootMap with stuff needed for the Template

    // mocking method return
    when(mockedMyFile.getRootMap()).thenReturn(rootMap);

    // replacing the MyFile implementation with my Mock
    fileGenerator.setMyFile(mockedMyFile);

    // calling the method I want to test
    fileGenerator.createFile();

    assertTrue(MyFile.getFile().exists());
}
```

And here is a simplification of the code I'm testing:

```
public void createFile() {
    final Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(getClass(), "templates/");
    try {
        myFile.getFile().createNewFile();
        final Template template = cfg.getTemplate("template.ftl");
        final Writer writer = new FileWriter(myFile.getFile());
        template.process(myFile.getRootMap(), writer);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
    // exception handling
}
```

Comment: Since you're already using mockito, you can try powermock to mock static/final/private methods such as Class.getResource()

Comment: Really using **/src/main/test** for your test code and not **src/test/java** ?

Comment: @khmarbaise oops you're right, fixed my question

Comment: You could rework your class to be easier to test.  Freemarker `Configuration` objects are often used as singletons -- not built for each invocation. If the `Configuration` were injected into the class, then you could either mock it or use an alternate template loader in your test.

Comment: @CharlesForsythe thanks! Solved my problem injecting the TemplateLoader, but it does make more sense to use the Configuration as a singleton.

I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied Charles Forsythe's suggestion, it worked out fine.

I just added a templateLoader member to the FileGenerator class, with its own getter and setter.

Next, in my createFile method, I use the method setTemplateLoader(TemplateLoader) from the Configuration class, as such:

```
public void createFile() {
    final Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    // Changed
    cfg.setTemplateLoader(templateLoader);
    // the rest
}
```

Finally, I just create a template loader for my test:

```
@Test
public void shouldCreateFile() {
    final MyFile mockedMyFile = spy(file);
    final Map<String, Object> rootMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    TemplateLoader templateLoader = null;

    try {
        templateLoader = new FileTemplateLoader(new File("<PATH TO TEMPLATE FOLDER>"));
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    gerador.setTemplateLoader(templateLoader);
    // the rest
}
```

And problem solved. In my production code, I use ClassTemplateLoader instead of FileTemplateLoader.